# Issue debugging PDBs from MyGet with VS and R#

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, nuget, symbols, pdb-files

I am attempting to debug NuGet source code (Project Foo is referencing Project Bar through a NuGet package in MyGet) and I'm stuck with "The breakpoint will not be currently hit, the current source code is different" error and I'm out of ideas.

What I did:

- Added MyGet symbol server in VS.
- Assembly built non-optimized with a full PDB.
- Unix-style .editorconfig for correct encoding and LF line endings (source code is in Git).

The symbols are in MyGet:
[image: MyGet symbols]

The modules appear to load correctly:
[image: Symbols loaded]

R# seems to be using the wrong hash and gives errors:

```
PdbNavigator: Downloader: https://private-symbol-server/symbols::Phx.Security.Web.NETCore.dll::02da18bf9fbf42e1bd6263e56ca57af8FFFFFFFF -> Ok (cached)
PdbNavigator: No debugging information found on symbol servers for Phx.Security.Web.NETCore, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
```

VS complains about the source code being different when I manually add breakpoints to the source file:
[image: Source code is different]

I'm open to all suggestions and ideas at this point!

Answer (score 0):

> The breakpoint will not be currently hit, the current source code is
>   different error

It complains that the xx.cs file found by VS is bit different from the version used to build the xx.dll. I assume maybe you have some changes made to the xx.cs file after you built the xx.dll and publish it to your nuget server.

You can try rebuilding the Nuget project, and push its source files, pdb and assembly to your Symbol Server the second time. (Clean the existing versions)

After that create a new project in new solution to consume that package and check if the issue persists. (Not sure if the original Bar project would affect the debugging while they're in same solution, so please create a new solution to check)

Also, you can work around this error by Go Debug menu => Options => General =>  Disable the `Require source files to exactly match the original version` option.

Most of the time we should select this option to make sure what we are seeing is what we are running during debug process, but since this is your personal project, if you can make sure the xx.cs and assembly in your symbol server is the right version you want, you can try to disable it when debugging your nuget project. See the [recommended configuration](http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Home/VisualStudio).

Comment: Hi, Lance. The projects are in different solutions and I tried multiple times cleaning, redeploying, and referencing the new versions. I understand that I can disable the exact match requirement but that does not explain how the files are different, which is what I am trying to resolve. Let me go through all the other recommended configuration options and get back to you on that.

Comment: I followed all the recommendations except disabling source matching and am still getting the same warning. Do you know how I can discover the differences between the files?

Comment: @denious Make sure the bar package is built in Debug mode and the Foo is consuming the package in debug mode also. And clean the nuget package cache to make sure you're not using the earlier versions. (If you're using packagereference format, it will fetch packages from `C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages`, every time when you add nuget package in VS, it will search if it exists in that folder, if it exist, your new project will actually use that old package ) See [this](https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/6987/how-to-clear-nuget-cache),In VS, go Tools menu=>nuget pckage manager=>Package manager settings.

Comment: Cache cleared, same effect. We have CICD that rolls up the package version on each upload so shouldn't be an issue either way. The package is built in Release but without optimization with a full PDB (i.e. not portable) and consumed in Debug. Is this configuration not sufficient?

Comment: I once saw someone who met similar issue said this warning will occur when trying to debug an assembly from release mode, but I fail to find it now. You can check if it make sense when you debug the assembly comes from debug mode, also apart from nuget cache, you can also delete the .vs, bin and obj and restart the vs to check. I'll continue on this and try to reproduce this issue, but probably it takes some time :) Note: Build the assembly before adding any breakpoint in it.